# Grouping XML multiple elements into a single one

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0, xslt-grouping

This is my XML file for which we have write an xsl file. Purpose for this  xsl is to use for XML operation.

Input XML

```
<ns1:POOrder xmlns:ns1="http://tanole/SO11/ERP_PD_EMS/RD_SalesOrder_Defirm">
    <RIOrder>
        <Order>
           <SerialNo>0922830281</SerialNo>
            <ItemID>2345</ItemID>
            <OrderNo>0128333331</OrderNo>
        </Order>
        <Order>
            <SerialNo>0922830281</SerialNo>
            <ItemID>2345</ItemID>
            <OrderNo>0128333331</OrderNo>
        </Order>
    </RIOrder>
</ns1:POOrder>
```

Expected Output:

```
<RIOrders>
  <R1 OrderNo="0128333331" ItemID="2345"  SerialNo="0922830281"/>
</RIOrders>
```

I am trying to implement this logic in my xsl file, but unable to get so.This is what I am currently trying to do, I have tried a few things and cannot figure out a way to do what I need.

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:key name="orders" match="Order" use="OrderNo" />
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <RIOrders>
            <xsl:for-each select="RIOrder/Order[generate-id() = generate-id(key('orders', OrderNo)[1])]">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="key('orders', OrderNo)" />
            </xsl:for-each>
        </RIOrders>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Order">
        <R1 OrderNo="{OrderNo}" ItemID="{ItemID}" SerialNo="{SerialNo}" UpdateDateOn="N" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I need to eliminate duplicate elements from my XML using a specific node OrderNo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want duplicate `<Order>` elements in the output, don't apply templates to the group members, but to the group.

You currently do "for each group, apply templates to all elements of the group":

```
<xsl:for-each select="RIOrder/Order[generate-id() = generate-id(key('orders', OrderNo)[1])]">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('orders', OrderNo)" />
</xsl:for-each>
```

whereas you actually want to do:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="RIOrder/Order[generate-id() = generate-id(key('orders', OrderNo)[1])]" />
```

Output for your sample input is:

```
<RIOrders>
   <R1 OrderNo="0128333331" ItemID="2345" SerialNo="0922830281" UpdateDateOn="N" />
</RIOrders>
```

Comment: Tomalak but i am getting output like that <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RIOrders/>

Comment: I don't think so. I've tested the code and it produces exactly one `<R1>` element.

Comment: I applied second one it is working <!--<xsl:apply-templates select="key('orders', OrderNo)" />-->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>

Comment: You are supposed to **remove** the `<xsl:for-each>`. I thought that would be clear.

Comment: Don't forget to accept one of the answers. And definitely vote on both of them, as soon as you can (at 15 rep points upvotes will be enabled, that should not take very long). Votes are this site's way to say "thank you".

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:key name="orders" match="Order" use="OrderNo" />
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <RIOrders>
            <xsl:for-each select="RIOrder/Order[generate-id() = generate-id(key('orders', OrderNo)[1])]">
                 <R1 OrderNo="{OrderNo}" ItemID="{ItemID}" SerialNo="{SerialNo}" UpdateDateOn="N" />
            </xsl:for-each>
        </RIOrders>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Note that you are grouping by `OrderNo`. The other values (`ItemID` and `SerialNo`) will be taken from the first member of the group (in document order). If there are other values in the group, they will be lost.